# What-if-will construct

Tags: questions, will-future

Sometimes i face people use `will` to express a future in questions (rarely, though):

> What if we will get just 30–60 active accounts?

1. I know what-if-will may be used in some cases, but, as i understand, in the example above `will` must be omitted. I'm i right ?
2. I believe native speakers would have understood me if i had asked such a question, but what it sounds like for them ?

Any explanation is appreciated :)

Comment: It can. On the other hand, the sentence with the *will* is more suited for asking what would follow *now* from knowing that we will get just 30-60 active accounts. The one without it ask for what would follow then, once we get just 30-60 active accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not say "what if we will get ... ". I use "will" in protasis of a conditional only if it means "be willing to" or "be obstinate/foolhardy enough to".

I would say that as "What if we get ...", or "What if we *do* get ... " for emphasis.